# ¿Como instalar una apk desde mi aplicación usando comandos?

Tags: android

Mi problema es que necesito poder instalar un apk que se encuentra en la sdcard de android, mediante comandos, yo se que existe una forma que es mediante el uso Intent, pero lo que necesito son comandos.

Mis códigos:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c pm install /sdcard/Mostrador_1.0.apk");
```

y también probé con:

```
Process process1 =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c adb install /sdcard/Mostrador_1.0.apk");
```

Comment: qué fallos te da?

Comment: No la instala. Gracias

Comment: encontes: no falla y no instala? Tienes algun tipo de log ?

Comment: Tienes en el manifest el permiso de instalar apk?

Comment: Hay un permiso para eso. Gracias